# Using gdalbuildvrt in R gives Warning Message ... had status 1?

Tags: qgis, gdal, r, mosaic, gdalbuildvrt

I want to make a mosaic out of several raster files that are next to each other, all including 4 bands. Due to saving space on the server I need to build a vrt and want to write the code in R, so I can process this action more often without too much work. Unfortunately I cannot get rid of the Warning message:

```
    Warning message:
    running command '"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16\bin\gdalbuildvrt.exe"  
    -overwrite  
    "S:/Raster/Ortho_Mosaic.vrt" "S:/Raster/Input/*.tiff"'    
    had status 1
```

I use R and gdalbuildvrt should use gdal from QGIS 2.16.

My packages are rgdal, raster and gdalUtils. 
My code looks like this:

```
    folder <- 'S:/Raster/'
    gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = paste(folder, '/Input/*.tiff', sep = ""),
    output.vrt= paste(folder, '/Ortho_Mosaic.vrt', sep = ""), 
    intern = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE))
```

I tried a lot of different ways for my input files:  use an extent, use single files, all .tif files or changed tif to tiff ... 
The output file is not produced even though it is only a warning and not an error message. All files are in the same coordinate system; EPSG 31467

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have success by using the gdalbuildvrt command directly from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked immediately. I would just prefer it to work in R because then the script can be used as some kind of documentation and within a big group of people working on similar data it would be benificial to use the exact same method. Do you have any idea why command line is no problem at all and in R i cannot make it work? Might there be any issue in R? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Is `Orhto_Mosaic.vrt` a typo in your question or in your script?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Unfortunately just in the question... Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Warning messages are not supposed to be critical. Have you checked if new .vrt file is generated anyhow?

Comment: I checked, but unfortunately nothing was created. I was also puzzled that it is just a warning message, but actually looks like an error. The message is produced after a fraction of a second, so it seems not to calculate anything.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code a bit and it looks like I had problem with the paths. I am not sure though if this warning (/error) message is a sign in general that the path is wrong.

My paths look now like this with less frontslashes:

```
    folder_lisa_2015 <-'S:/Raster/'
    gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = paste(folder, 'Input/*.tif', sep = ''), 
    output.vrt= paste(folder_lisa_2015, 'Ortho_Mosaic.vrt'), intern = TRUE, 
    overwrite = TRUE)
```

If it would not be for so many files, I would prefer the nice solution by @user30184 and process the mosaic in command line!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following worked:

```r
gdalbuildvrt <- system2(
                    command="gdalbuildvrt",
                    args=c( "/path/to/mosaic.vrt", "/path/to/*.tif" )
                )
```